# Brute Force and Minimax/AlphaBeta pruning

Tags: brute-force, minimax, alpha-beta-pruning

Brute Force is essentially just searching every possible combination but how is minimax any different? Minimax searches every combination as well and then returns the best score?

I understand that when we used alpha beta pruning we take out ones that will have no effect on our min/max value but this occurs after we have already performed minimax so would this be considered brute force? Maybe I'm misunderstanding what I've been reading so far, so any help would be great!

Thank You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alpha-beta pruning does not occur "after" minimax, it occurs "during" minimax. And the pruning does in fact eliminate a vast number of "combinations" -- down to sqrt of the brute-force minimax number in the best case, n^(3/4) in the average case.

Answer (score 0):

Minimax is a much more efficient way to walk through the decision tree than brute force. As only nodes that might still contain a better solution are visited, in contrary to brute force where **all** nodes are visited, without pruning of any kind.

[Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brute-force_search):

> Heuristics can also be used to make an early cutoff of parts of the search. One example of this is the minimax principle for searching game trees, that eliminates many subtrees at an early stage in the search.

In Minimax you cut parts of the tree depending on the available moves and their score, meaning that you would not go over all the possibilities, and this makes it superior to brute-force approach.

Comment: You're not differentiating between Alpha-Beta pruning and Minimax. Minimax does indeed visit every possible game state regardless of the result it hopes to achieve from it. I believe what you're referring to should be labelled as a form of Alpha-Beta not Minimax.

Comment: Yes, wikipedia is wrong in this case -- used the wrong term, "minimax" instead of "alpha-beta".